# Ayuda con conexión BD a Windows forms Visual Basic

Tags: sql, visual-studio

Alguíen puede ayudarme con esto, lo que sucede es que intento conectar la base de datos pero me sale un error por lo que mi base de datos tiene un "\" esta así:

```
private SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Data Source=URIELKASTRO\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=tienda;Integrated Security=True");
```

Cuando veo por que falla dice: Representa texto como una secuencia de unidades de código UTF-16 para examinar el codigo fuente de .NETframwork para este tipo, consulte el reference resource, luego dice secuencia de escape no reconocida

Estaría agradecido por su ayuda Gracias <3

Comment: Para no errarle, abri el SqlManagement, cuando te dice que te queres conectar al motor en el login, ahi tenes la cadena de conexion que tenes que pegar en VB.

Answer (score 0):

El Data Source es el nombre de tu equipo, esta seria la cadena de conexion, My.Computer.Name (obtiene el nombre de tu computadora)

```
private SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" & My.Computer.Name & ";Initial Catalog=tienda;Integrated Security=True")
```

el "." funciona de la misma manera

```
private SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=tienda;Integrated Security=True")
```

Comment: Dice que My no existe en el contexto actual :c

Comment: Entonces puedes utilizar el "." funciona de la misma manera

private SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=tienda;Integrated Security=True")